# Getting object within vector based on object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, stl

I'm trying to iterate through a vector of Player objects and then return the next one based off a Player pointer. I have tried various ways to get the operators within the lambda to match but cannot get it to work and have read similar such issues on stack overflow. I'm sorry for not making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), I just don't know how at my current skill level.

**Source of c_player:**
Defined as:

```
Player* current_player;
```

Set with:

```
void Game::set_first_player_turn(){
    current_player = &game_players.back();
}
```

**Erroneous code:**

```
using namespace std;
vector<Player>game_players;

Player* Game::find_player(Player* c_player){
    vector<Player>::iterator iter;
    iter = find_if(game_players.begin(), game_players.end(),
                   [&](Player* p ) -> bool{ return p == c_player; }); //This line
                                        // causes the exception. Sets iterator to
                                        // position of the current player
    if (iter != game_players.end()){
        advance(iter, 1);
    }
    else{
        iter == game_players.begin();
    }
    current_player = &(*iter);  

    return current_player;
}
```

**Compile error:**

```
error C2664: 'bool Game::set_game_flow::<lambda_360ac8a355100cfac1adc9f8eba8d8b9>
::operator ()(Player *) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Player' 
to 'Player *'
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predicate in `find_if` has to take a const reference to a type stored in container. You store a `Player` type in vector

```
vector<Player> game_players;
```

Thus

```
[&](Player* p )
```

is not a correct predicate. This should be

```
[c_player]( const Player& p ) { return p == *c_player; } 
                                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    // to compare by value
// note: to compare by value 
// bool operator==( const Player&, const Player&)
// must be defined

[c_player]( const Player& p ) { return &p == c_player; } 
                                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    // to compare by address
// note: address of c_player
// has to be valid (not invalidated by vector through resizing, erasing, etc)
```

So you can write:

```
vector<Player>::iterator iter;
iter = find_if( game_players.begin(), game_players.end(),
                       [c_player]( const Player& p ) { return p == *c_player;});
```

Comment: With `iter = find_if(game_players.begin(), game_players.end(),[](const Player& p ) { return p == *c_player; });` I get the error: `C3493: 'c_player' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified`

Comment: you have to capture a c_player in []

Comment: This gives: `error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Player' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: do you want to compare addresses or do a value comparison? In second case you need bool operator==( const Player&, const Player&) to be defined

Comment: I'm actually not sure which one would suit my need. `c_player` is originally obtained from `game_players`. I just need it to 'find' it iwthin the vector so that `if (iter != game_players.end()){advance(iter, 1);}` works. So if either comparing addresses or value comparison is the way to go, I don't mind. I'm just looking for that functionality. And on that note, if I'm going about it in the wrong way, feel free to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: simpler is to compare addresses but you have to be sure address of c_player is still valid (vector hasn't invalidated it by resizing, etc)

Comment: I've edited the post to show the source of how c_player is obtained.

Comment: so you take the address of c_player, then do some things with vector, so you know that now c_player is not at vector.back() and then want to find c_player? Then you cannot use address. Use value comparison: return p == *c_player;

Comment: Excellent help thanks very much. `iter = find_if(game_players.begin(), game_players.end(),[c_player](const Player& p ) { return &p == c_player; });` was the solution I needed.